# Consumers are not returning connection to my DB connection pool

Tags: java, database, algorithm, c#-4.0

I have a Data base connection pool. There are consumers who take connection from that pool. 
But i cant trust those consumers because lot of them are not returning my connection back. Hence the pool starves and many consumers are forced too wait for infinite.
for example:

```
class Consumer{
    void someMethod(){
        Connection con=Pool.getConnection();
        //some bloody steps which throws exception
        con.goodBye();//giving back the connection to the pool
    }
}
```

Because of the exception and may be because of arrogance the connection is not given back always. I have no way to restrict the usage of Pool api in the consumers' class.

How can i get my connection back?.(I have no way to force the Consumer)
I believe there is no fool proof solution for this(May be im not that smart). Still can any one can come up with a pretty good solution.
One solution which i got is checking whether any exception occurs in the Consumer class, if Exception occurs then take back the connection force fully.

Or is there any new revolutionary DBPool design pattern which are not very popular for this type of typical scenarios(even though i think that my case is very generic, any one can forget to give back the connection back to the pool.)

Comment: This is more an administrative/management issue than of programming. You can't resolve all troubles in the world just sitting in the cubicle and coding. For this one I would make up a list of poor programmed clients and raise this issue with their management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not return connection objects, return proxy objects representing connections instead. These proxy objects, when finalized, should say goodbye to the connection they stand for. If a proxy is not properly closed, it will eventually be garbage-collected, and adjust the connection state at this time.

Two issues here. First, the time before GC is unpredictable. Better than forever, but still can be very long. Second, be aware of side effects of complex calls in the finalizer, object resurrection in particular. There are some rare but ugly scenarios that prevent objects to be collected at all.

Comment: I think this solution is having the least over head

Answer (score 2):

That's bad client code. The code should handle the case of an exception and close the connection when done.

There's no way for you to know from your code if that's not being done, though. It's the client  code's fault and problem if it doesn't do that.

Having a sane timeout is the only way to limit this, but it still does not "solve" it, ultimately.

--

You mention in comments that this pool is shared among multiple clients. That shifts the responsibility back to you, of course.

Can you limit each client to only using X connections at once? This way, at least they can only tie up so many at one time.

Otherwise, you could create separate pools per client. That sort of just moves the problem down the stack, but might be appropriate, depending on the logistics involved.

Comment: Consider this case.
I agree with you. Fault lies with that particular client. But there are n clients and if 1 client did some thing wrong, it should not affect the other clients

Comment: I can limit the no of connections for a particular client. But it doesn't resolve the issue. Separate Pool for separate will solve the issue. But i don't think that it practical. I will restrict the no of connections allowed to a particular client, even though there are too many free connection(allocated for other clients).

Comment: Unfortunately, you simply must at some point rely on your consumers doing the "right" thing. You basically have a trust/user education issue here.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you look at using `WeakReference`, here you can adjust your code to return a weak reference to a connection, when the thread using the connection dies, the object will have no  reference (except from your `WeakHashMap`), you can then periodically identify these objects and call the `goodBye` method using a thread.

[here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp11225/) is an article which can help you understand this better.

.net also has a `WeakReference` class which behaves very similar to this.

Comment: I suspect this might not be helpful in this case. It's basically implementing a connection timeout, but with a different pattern than would typically be used.

Comment: yes, i agree, the trouble here is when the client doesn't follow the standards, you can still do something to keep track of things.. this is one way of doing it.. I agree its a round about way but it has worked for me in a few situations.

Comment: I think this is a great idea. Thank you

Comment: Weak references are of no use here. What object exactly are you proposing to weakly reference? Connections in the pool are already strongly referenced. And "threads" using the objects do not "die", rather in the original question the references are dropped on the floor. Could you please elaborate on that? Your answer is rather unclear as it stands.

Comment: the idea here is to use a weakhashmap to store the connection object.. and return the weakly referenced object to the client. when the client doesn't call the close method and has terminated (like a thread which is using the connection and is no more) the weakreference can be used to call the close method.. this is a round about way of solving the issue, best way would be to enforce people to call the close method.. but that usually doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried catching the exception and closing the connection in the catch clause?

```
class Consumer{
    void someMethod(){
        Connection con=Pool.getConnection();
        try{
             //some bloody steps which throws exception
        }catch(Exception e){
             con.goodBye();
        }
        con.goodBye();//giving back the connection to the pool
    }
}
```

Edit: you could also use a `finally` block to remove the redundant code and make sure your connection gets closed in every case. I am assuming this is java code, no experience with C#.

Comment: I agree with you. But unfortunately the consumer part is implemented by external user. I mean i supply the Pool API's and its up to the consumer to user it.

Comment: @Arshed Then it's not your responsibility at all. You have provided a well-established api that the consumer is willfully ignoring.

Comment: Case is like this. There is one mysql(or whatever DB) database. This mysql has 'N' no of databases. I have 'm' customer/client. They connect to their respective DB suing my pool. Client1 takes some connection and never returned back, should never effect Client2. I agree, let the client1 suffers for his sin. But why client2

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is not to give the consumers access to the connection pool directly, but have your own list of connections. Then reclaim the connection after a timeout, say 60 seconds.

Comment: How can i do that? The consumer may be doing some transaction at that time, if i do that it will result in an unstable system.

Comment: There should be a timeout, yes. But if that timeout is too short, you'll have other problems. And most connection pool mechanisms don't expose the pool "directly", anyway... that's kind of the point.

Comment: First, your system sounds unstable at the moment. If comsumers are genuinely taking a connection for more than a minute, you may need to increase the time (I seem to remember something about Google imposing a 30 second limit). Is Pool.getConnection(); under you control? You would redefine this to get a connection from your list rather than directly from the pool.